# <InputSelect> selected value not changing when option is changed on the web page Blazor .NET 8

Tags: drop-down-menu, blazor

I am writing an `InputForm` named `ClassForm` in blazor .NET 8.0 that handles the data of a class `Class`. Every `Class` belongs to a `Region`. I am saving the data of regions into a different table.

```
@if(Item is not null)
{
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            <EditForm Enhance=true FormName="ClassForm" Model=Item OnValidSubmit="AddOrEditData" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                @if (IsEditMode)
                {
                    <input type="hidden" value="@Item.Id" />
                }
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="@Item.Name" class="form-label">
                        Class
                    </label>
                    <InputText id="year" @bind-Value=Item.Name class="form-control shadow-none" />
                </div>
                
@*                 
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="@Item.Region" class="form-label">
                        Region
                    </label>
                    <select id="region" bind=@SelectedRegionId class="form-select">
                        @if(regions is not null)
                        {
                            <option value="0">Select Region</option>
                            @foreach (var reg in regions)
                            {
                                <option value="@reg.Id">@reg.Name</option>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <option value="-9999">Please add a region to continue with this operation</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    <div><p>@SelectedRegionId</p></div>
                </div>

 *@
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="@Item.Region" class="form-label">Region</label>
                    <InputSelect id="region-dp" @bind-Value="@Item.Region" class="form-control">
                        @if (regions is not null)
                        {
                            <option selected value="@Guid.Empty"></option>
                            @foreach (Region reg in regions)
                            {
                                <option value="@reg.Id">@reg.Name</option>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <option value="-9999">Please add a region to continue with this operation</option>
                        }
                    </InputSelect>
                    <div><p>@SelectedRegionId</p></div>
                </div>

                
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for=@Item.KeyStage class="form-label">
                        Key Stage
                    </label>
                    <InputSelect id="ketstage" @bind-Value="Item.KeyStage" class="form-select">
                        <option value="0">Select Key Stage</option>
                        @foreach (var ks in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyStagesEnum)))
                        {
                            <option value="@ks">@ks.ToString()</option>
                        }
                    </InputSelect>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="@Item.AgeGroup" class="form-label">Age Group</label>
                    <InputSelect id="agfrp" @bind-Value="Item.AgeGroup" class="form-select">
                        <option value="0">Select Age Group</option>
                        @foreach (var grp in Enum.GetValues(typeof(AgeGroupsEnum)))
                        {
                            <option value="@grp">@grp.ToString()</option>
                        }
                    </InputSelect>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="@Item.Description" class="form-label">Remarks</label>
                    <InputTextArea @bind-Value=Item.Description class="form-control"></InputTextArea>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow-none">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                    <a href="/classes/list" class="btn btn-secondary shadow-none ms-3">
                        Back to List
                    </a>
                </div>
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <ValidationSummary/>
            </EditForm> 
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

On the `ClassForm` I am using an `InputSelect` component that shows regions in a dropdown. User selects the region that this class belongs to.

```
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="@Item.Region" class="form-label">Region</label>
                    <InputSelect id="region-dp" @bind-Value="@Item.Region" class="form-control">
                        @if (regions is not null)
                        {
                            <option selected value="@Guid.Empty"></option>
                            @foreach (Region reg in regions)
                            {
                                <option value="@reg.Id">@reg.Name</option>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <option value="-9999">Please add a region to continue with this operation</option>
                        }
                    </InputSelect>
```

But when I choose any option from gthe dropdown, it does not change value.

That is why when I click the `Submit` button it gives the error

[Error displayed when i click Submit Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN7SY.png)

I am doubtful for one more thing. I am trying to dave data in `Classes`, but the error shows that it trying to save data in `Regions`

The `@Code` block of the razor page is whoen below.

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsEditMode { get; set; } = false;

    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title => IsEditMode ? $"Edit Class {Id}" : "Add New Class";


    public string SelectedRegionId{ get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public ELevel? Item { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<ELevel> OnDataValidated { get; set; }



    public List<Region>? regions{ get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (IsEditMode)
        {
            Item ??= await Repo.GetByIdAsync(Id);
        }
        else
        {
            Item ??= new();
        }

        regions = await regrepo.GetAllAsync();

    }

    private async Task AddOrEditData()
    {
        // Region? reg = await regrepo.GetByIdAsync(SelectedRegionId);


        // if(reg is not null)
        // {
        //     if(Item is not null)
        //     {
        //         Item.Region = reg;
        //     }
        // }

        await OnDataValidated.InvokeAsync(Item);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me solev this issue?

This is also available at [this site](http://difripedia.com)

Answer (score 0):

You region select is using an Id [which looks like a Guid] as the value and is bound to  `@bind-Value="@Item.Region"`.  However, your SQL error relates to the `RegionId` or `Id` field.

Unless you're using different Domain and Infrastructure objects, the above code and error suggests your select is bound to the wrong field -  `Region` [probably a text field] when it should be bound to `RegionId` or `Id`.

Comment: 'RegionID' is a column of 'Classes' table that refers to 'Id' column in the 'Regions' table. The <InputSelect> should display region name from the 'Regions' table. The data will be saved in 'Classes' table.

Comment: What's the data type of `RegionID` and `Id`?  I think you should be binding to `@bind-Value="@Item.RegionID"`.

Comment: I have a property 'Public virtual Region Region {get; set;}' in the 'ELevel' model. Should use 'Public int RegionID{get; set;}' instead? Then how shall I relate data?